# Рекурсивное дублирование элементов односвязного списка

Tags: рекурсия, память, pascal, список

Добрый вечер всем. Нужна помощь - есть реализация линейного односвязного списка на Паскале. Данной процедурой хочу продублировать все положительные элементы, однако выбрасывает переполнение буфера, зацикливает. Не могу обнаружить ошибку, помогите пожалуйста.

```
 procedure doublePlus(var start: link);
    var
      p: link;
    begin
      if start <> nil then begin
        if start^.inf > 0 then begin
          new(p);
          p^.inf := start^.inf;
          p^.next := start^.next;
          start^.next := p;
        end doublePlus(start^.next)
      end 
    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если start^.inf > 0, то Вы создаёте дубль start^, а затем с этим дублем проделываете то же самое. Измените рекурсивный вызов для случая start^.inf > 0 на doublePlus(p^.next), иначе doulePlus(start^.next)

Comment: Большое спасибо @alexlz - всё работает!